# Como obter o valor de uma propriedade com Expression?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando obter o valor de uma propriedade através de `Expression`, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

> A propriedade de instância '.Rota.NomeDaAplicacao' não está definida
>   para o tipo
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.FilaRaiz_9328343013D3BB166E625F779B61FC319EEB1BBB98D8E88250DA9549AF70A0C8'

Minha implementação que estou tentando fazer é a seguinte.

```
private string ObterValorDoObjeto(Object obj, string propriedade)
{
    Expression propertyExpr = Expression.Property(
        Expression.Constant(obj),
        propriedade
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(propertyExpr).Compile()();
}
```

E a chamada dela.

```
 var TemplateDeURI = ObterValorDoObjeto(fila, ".Rota.NomeDaAplicacao");
```

Meu objeto `fila` tem um objeto de navegação (Classe) `Rota` que tem a propriedade `NomeDaAplicacao`, e essa a propriedade que eu quero obter o valor,, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Rota é outra classe dentro do tipo de objeto instância `fila`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, isso mesmo  public Rota Rota { get; set; }

Comment: Entendi, você vai precisar fazer uma recursão ou reflexão para navegar entre os objetos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode dividir a string e percorrer o array gerando uma `Expression` e passando ela mesmo como parâmetro:

```
public static string ObterValorExp(object obj, string prop)
{
    string[] props = prop.Split('.');

    Expression exp = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(obj), props[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < props.Length; i++)
    {
          exp = Expression.Property(exp, props[i]);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp).Compile()();
}
```

Coloquei no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jmkFRS)

---

Você também pode usar Reflection, e com um método recursivo percorrer o objeto até chegar na propriedade final:

```
public static object ObterValor(object obj, string prop)
{
    string[] props = prop.Split('.');

    PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(props[0]);

    var xObj = pi.GetValue(obj, null);

    if (props.Length > 1)
    {
        string auxProp = String.Join(".", props,1, props.Length-1);
        return ObterValor(xObj, auxProp);
    }
    else
    {
        return xObj;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/553UIb)

*Não fiz nenhum tratamento de erro, com mais tempo vou melhorando o código*