# Como exibir os valores dos campos de duas classes em um DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou populando um objeto `DataGridView` com uma lista de classes de tipo `List<Curso>`, e a forma que eu populo o `DataGridView` é da seguinte maneira:

```
meuDataGridView.DataSource = cursos;
```

Porém, um dos campos da minha classe `Curso` é outra classe, que no caso é a classe `Instituicao`. E na visualização dos dados no grid o campo `Nome` da classe `Instituicao` não aparece corretamente.

Segue uma imagem de ilustração dos dados no grid:

[image: ilustração do DataGridView]

## Reproduzindo o exemplo mínimo

Para reproduzir o exemplo mínimo de ilustração do problema, você vai precisar da classe `Curso` da classe `Instituicao` e de um formulário com um `DataGridView`.

Classe Curso:

```
class Curso
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public Instituicao Instituicao { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Instituicao:

```
public class Instituicao
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Classe do formulário com o `DataGridView` e dados populados nele:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cursos = new List<Curso>
        {
            new Curso
            {
                Descricao = "Curso Java",
                CargaHoraria = 99999999,
                Instituicao = new Instituicao
                {
                    Nome = "Instituicao Javali"
                }

            },
            new Curso
            {
                Descricao = "Curso Python",
                CargaHoraria = 1,
                Instituicao = new Instituicao
                {
                    Nome = "Monty Python"
                }
            },
            new Curso
            {
                Descricao = "Curso de PHP",
                CargaHoraria = -99999999,
                Instituicao = new Instituicao
                {
                    Nome = "Instituicao no fim da galaxia"
                }
            }
        };

        PopulaGrid(cursos);
    }

    private void PopulaGrid(List<Curso> cursos)
    {
        if (cursos != null && cursos.Any())
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = cursos;
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Pergunta

Como eu posso exibir o valor da propriedade `Nome` da classe `Instituicao` no grid ao invés daquele valor incomum?

Comment: `new Curso { Descricao = "Curso Java", CargaHoraria = 99999999, Nome = "Instituicao Javali" }`?

Comment: @Maniero a classe `Instituicao` possui mais campos, esse é só um exemplo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar várias formas:

Objeto anônimo:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = cursos.Select(x=> new { Descrição = x.Descricao, Instituição = x.Instituicao.Nome  }).ToList();
```

Adicionar uma propriedade em Cursos, que retorne apenas o Nome da Instituição:

```
public class Curso
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public Instituicao Instituicao { get; set; }

    public string InstituicaoNome => this.Instituicao.Nome;
}
```

Sobrescrever o método ToString, mas esse só aplicável em uma propriedade:

```
public class Instituicao
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Nome;
    }
}
```

Ou, formatar o valor durante o evento CellFormating do DataGridView:

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (column.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        object data = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        string[] properties = column.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length && data != null; i++)
            data = data.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]).GetValue(data);
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = data;
    }
}
```

Esse último, acho o mais custoso, e foi retirado do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863096/4713574

> Não está diretamente ligado, mas relacionado: [Como obter o valor de uma propriedade com Expression](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313700/69359)

Answer (score 2):

Como sua classe Instituição possui só uma propriedade, o adequado talvez seria coloca-la dentro de curso. Mas isso depende de como você quer usa-lo mais tarde. Outras soluções seriam dar um override no `ToString` imprimindo o nome da instituição:

```
public class Instituicao
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Nome;
    }
}
```

Ou criar um objeto anônimo com os dados completos:

```
private void PopulaGrid(List<Curso> cursos)
{
    if (cursos != null && cursos.Any())
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cursos.Select(c => new { c.CargaHoraria, c.Descricao, Instituição = c.Instituicao.Nome }).ToList();
    }
}
```